# ble.scan() frow Web Workers

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-worker

Can you help me? How to start working with Bluetooth (cordova-ble-central) from Web Workers?

ble.scan([],5,function(device){postMessage(device.name)}, function(error){});

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you....

```
var devices=[];
        ble.startScan([],  
            function(peripheral)
            {
                devices.push(peripheral);
            },
            function(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            });

        setTimeout(ble.stopScan, 1500,
            function() 
            {                    
                console.log("scan stopped.)
            },
            function() 
            {
                console.log("stopScan failed");
            }
```